# same session use in zf1 , zf2 project

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2, zend-session, zend-framework-modules

I have two application in zf1 and zf2 on save server, I have created login system in zf2, when i login zf2 it working fine.
Now i want to access zf2 session in zf1, it showing

```
   [zf2_auth] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
   (
          [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject
   )
```

How can resolve this i want to run both zf1 & zf2 application run on same session.

Here is directory structure for my project

```
project
--project/zf1_project
--project/zf2_project
```

Some times i manually create session in zf1 than run zf2, i have unable to get session as i want in zf2.

Any way by which i can use same login/Auth for both zf1 & zf2 application

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

ZF use object for store session. When start session, php try unserialize $_SESSION variable and if not found object's class PHP create __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object.

You should start session after classes autoload

Set session.auto_start=0 for fix it.